# Why does my custom launchd service fail with a status 78?

Tags: mac, services

I was writing a service to execute a command when some file on my Macbook changes following [Run Script on File Change on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/163985/run-script-on-file-change-on-mac-os-x).

This is my service file (`~/Library/LaunchAgents/my-service.plist)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my-service</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/<username>/.../onchange.sh</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/my-service.error</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/my-service.log</string>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/<username>/.../file-to-monitor.txt</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I bootstrapped my service and it failed with status 78. Following the advices on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215527/what-does-launchd-status-78-mean-why-my-user-agent-not-running, I used LaunchControl to debug and did find some permission related bugs and followed the in-app instructions to fix them. But it stilled failed even after I unload and reload my service.

My script `onchange.sh` has the content:

```
echo 123;
```

and permission:

```
-rwxr--r--@   1 <username>  staff    164 Aug  5 08:43 onchange.sh
```

But I couldn't find anything in `my-service.log` or `my-service.error` after reloading it and make some changes in `file-to-monitor.txt` to trigger the execution.

I am the first time using launchd. Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: What the heck does `/.../` mean here? It is not a directory, right? Shouldn’t it be `/Users/<username>/.onchange.sh` and `/Users/<username>/file-to-monitor.txt`?

Comment: Do you have permission to write to `/usr/local/var/log/my-service.log`? Is the script or the path it's watching in a [protected private subdirectory of your home](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)?